# Bean definition in spring integration

Tags: spring

I am new to spring. I want to write a bean definition for the code below.

```
package com.abc.common.filter;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class RegexFilter implements Filter<String> {

   Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(RegexFilter.class);
   private Pattern regex;
   private String lastMatch;   

   public RegexFilter(String regexString) {
      this.lastMatch = null;
      regex = Pattern.compile(regexString, Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS);
   }

   @Override
   public boolean matches(String text) {
      text = text.toLowerCase();
      if (text == null) {
         logger.error("No text set for matching!");
         return false;
      }

      Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(text);
      if (matcher.find(0)) {// always start at index 0
         this.lastMatch = matcher.group();
         if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug(matcher.group() + " found!");
         }
         return true;
      }

      return false;
   }

   public String getLastMatch(){
      return this.lastMatch;
   }

}
```

I am stuck after this line, i dont know how to include index or name? A little more clarification on index and values would be more than helpful.

```
<bean id="regexfilter" class="com.abc.common.filter.RegexFilter" />
    <constructor-arg name="regexString"  />
        </bean>
```

Comment: What error are you getting ? or where are you having trouble ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your bean

```
<bean id="regexfilter" class="com.abc.common.filter.RegexFilter" />
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="valueforregexstring"/>
</bean>
```

You can see more about bean definitions here
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/constructor_based_dependency_injection.htm

Answer (score 0):

in annotation based manor with pure java you can do something like this:

```
@Configuration
public class ApplicationConfig {

    @Bean
    public Filter regexFilter() {
        return new RegexFilter("value_for_the_regex_filter");
    }
}
```

or simply:

```
@Service
public class RegexFilter implements Filter<String> {
    ...
}
```